# Meaning of "Ephete" in Seamus Heaney's "The Stations of the West"

Tags: meaning, poetry, seamus-heaney

So far, the only definition I've managed to get is "a member of an ancient Athenian court that tried certain murder cases" (Merriam-Webster), but since the poem is about traveling to the Gaeltacht to rediscover the Irish language, this definition doesn't really make sense. By context, I assume it means something like "talk!/say!/speak!", but I would like to know the exact meaning and what language it comes from. I suspect it could be Irish, but given the religious undertones it could also be Classical Greek.

> On my first night in the Gaeltacht the old woman
> spoke to me in English: 'You will be all right.' I sat on a
> twilit bedside listening through the wall to fluent
> Irish, homesick for a speech I was to extirpate.
> I had come west to inhale the absolute weather. The
> visionaries breathed on my face a smell of soup-
> kitchens, they mixed the dust of croppies' graves with
> the fasting spittle of our creed and anointed my lips.
> *Ephete*, they urged. I blushed but only managed a few
> words.
> Neither did any gift of tongues descend in my days
> in that upper room when all around me seemed to
> prophesy. But still I would recall the stations of the
> west, white sand, hard rock, light ascending like its
> definition over Rannafast and Errigal, Annaghry and
> Kincasslagh: names portable as altar stones,
> unleavened elements.
>
> <sub>Heaney, Seamus. "The Stations of the West." 1975. [*New Selected Poems 1966–1987*](https://archive.org/details/newselectedpoems0000hean/mode/2up). London: Faber, 1990. Accessed at archive.org 22 March 2024. p. [47](https://archive.org/details/newselectedpoems0000hean/page/46/mode/2up).</sub>

Comment: [One dictionary](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_New_English_Dictionary_on_Historical_P/dCgkAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=RA1-PA236&printsec=frontcover) says that it means "to command, impose." [Another](https://www.google.com/books/edition/ALLEN_S_SYNONYMES_AND_ANTONYMS/ZqweuM4ZH3AC?hl=en&gbpv=1&pg=PA272&printsec=frontcover) equates it to "magistrate, authority." Are either of those plausible?

Comment: @CDR Thanks for the information. I'm not sure if they fit. The imagery of being "anointed" with the ash of past Irish rebels ("croppies"),  would imply he is a kind of recruit or newcomer, so it doesn't make much sense to me for the higher-ups to urge him to "command" or act with authority etc. But maybe there's something about the context (literary or historical) that I'm missing.

Comment: I'm going to guess that it's a homonym of "Ephpheta", meaning "be opened", used during the baptism ceremony, and related to the curing of a deaf-mute in Mark 7:31-37 (https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=33343) So they are urging him to be cured of his muteness in Gaelic.

Comment: The anointing is also a baptism reference -- as that link says the lips are anointed during baptism.

Comment: @tgdavies Thanks! I think that solves it. It seems what I had thought of as a religious undertone is in fact a central element of the poem.

Comment: How can the spelling ephete be related to ephpheta?

Comment: I don't know Aramaic, but understand a bit of Hebrew. According to [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%AA%D7%97), the Aramaic verb is "petah" (פתח), same consonant root as Hebrew "patakh", both meaning "to open".

Comment: From [this online resource](http://arshama.classics.ox.ac.uk/downloads/Aramaic%20Skeleton%20Grammar%2004%20(Strong%20Verb).pdf), I would venture to guess that "Ephpheta" is probably originally "etpetah" (אתפתח), the imperative of the Ground External Passive stem (etpe'el). Perhaps there is a subsequent assimilation of tp(h) > p(h)p(h), and final -ah > e? Hopefully someone with actual knowledge of Aramaic can chime in.

Comment: Ah, forgot to add, possible degemination of p(h)p(h), or alternatively a typo by the author himself. Again, all mere conjecture, though.

Comment: I doubt an Irish poet would go to such lengths. There's something we are all missing here. And I have emailed the keepers of his texts to ask them.